# Imported service is undefined

Tags: angular

cartService always logs undefined. I'm not sure if it has to do with the abstract class since I've never used it before and have no idea what it does (I'm updating code which wasn't originally written by me). Using a regular class doesn't solve the problem though...

**product-utils.ts**

```
import { CartService } from '../services/cart.service';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

...

export abstract class ProductUtils {
  constructor(
    private cartService: CartService,
    protected store: Store<any>) {}

  addToCart() {
    this.cartService.addCartFinalProduct(foo); // ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addCartFinalProduct' of undefined
    ...
  }
}
```

Store is available unlike cartService for some reason.

I'm using Angular 5.

**cart.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class CartService {
  addCartFinalProduct() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: ProductUtils is abstact class? How do you initiate this class and Where do you provide CartService?

Comment: Is there a provider for the service in the module definition?

Comment: ProductUtils is imported and used from other several components using extends ProductUtils. CartService is provided in services.module which packs all services available.

Comment: Abstract classes basically allow you to express common design patterns. They are like interfaces in that way. They do not get instantiated, therefore you cannot inject into an abstract class, hence your injected service is undefined.

Comment: Removing abstract doesn't solve the problem. The service is still undefined.

Comment: where and how is `addToCart` called?

Answer (score 1):

You're instantiating a cartService in the constructor, which is correct, you're stating that `cartService` is of type `CartService`, you're not giving it a value. This is the reason the `console.log(this.cartService)` is logging as `undefined`.

You would need to return something from a method inside cartService and `console.log()` that response.

Example

`console.log(this.carService.SomeMethodWithAReturn());`

It is the same thing as creating a variable like so `public variable: string;` and then `console.log(this.variable)`, this will also return undefined, until you assign a value to it, like `public variable: string = 'random string';`, if you `console.log(variable)` now, you will see "random string" in the console.

Comment: I didn't know that and I just logged from the constructor for the sake of legibility. this.cartService is undefined inside methods too. I'll edit the code now.

Comment: I see you updated your question, my answer still applies

Comment: Is your service `@Injectable()`?

Comment: Yes, I've used it the same way in other components without any problems

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an abstract class instead of a regular class?

Comment: No idea, as I said I don't even know the difference... I'm updating someone else's code so I guess there's a reason for it to be an abstract class. Deleting abstract doesn't solve the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **`this`**

```
 constructor(
    private cartService: CartService,
    protected store: Store<any>) {
       console.log(this.cartService);
}
```

Comment: It was a typo, I use this

Comment: oh i see, post your service